# TypeError: $locationProvider.when is not a function - angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to configure my angular However i keep getting the title error telling me ".when is not a function . below is my code.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : '/partials/main', 
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
        });
});

angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.myVar = "Hello Angular";
});
```

In a similar question on SO. I saw some one wrote his as below

```
angular.module('app').config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.when('/', {templateUrl : '/partials/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'});
}]);
```

arguing the two parameters have to be passed along with the config. ALl these fails. Please where do i go wrong ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should be `$routeProvider.when()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.when` belongs to [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider). Try this instead:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : '/partials/main', 
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    });
```

Comment: Hi, now it returns a different error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: I mean "Failed to load template: /partials/main (HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error)"

Comment: That's a server error, and you should post a new question with the relevant code to the server guys.

Answer (score 1):

`.when()` belongs to `$routeProvider` and not `$locationProvider`.

SO the correct code would be

```
angular.module('app').config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl : '/partials/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'});
}]);
```